# angularjs how to route 2 separate controllers on 2 separate pages for same module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a main page which has a module, the routing, a factory, and a controller.  Below is the first page and after that I've pasted in the second page.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect', 'myModule', 'ngMaterial',  'ui.router', 'angularMoment', 'breeze.directives', 'breeze.angular', 'ui.bootstrap.pagination']).run(['breeze', function (breeze) { }]);;
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Ordering");
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    $stateProvider       
        .state('Ordering', {
            url: '/Ordering',
            templateUrl: '/App/js/Ordering/Ordering.html'
        })
    .state('OrderingDetails', {
        url: '/OrderingDetails',
        templateUrl: '/App/js/Ordering/partials/OrderingDetails.html',
        controller: 'QtyUsedDetailsCtrl',
        resolve: {
            fromDate: function ($stateParams) {    
                return $stateParams.fromDate;
            },
        }
    })

});

myApp.config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
      .primaryPalette('blue-grey');
})

.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function ($scope, $mdSidenav) {
    $scope.toggleSidenav = function (menuId) {
        if ($scope.lockedOpen) {
            $scope.lockedOpen = "";
        }
        else {
            $scope.lockedOpen = "md-locked-open";
        }
    };

}])

.controller('OrderingListCtrl', [
    '$scope','$http', '$q', '$filter', '$location', '$window','$state','$stateParams', 'mydatacontext', 'breeze', 'OrderingService',
    function ($scope, $http, $q, $filter, $location, $window, $state, $stateParams, mydatacontext, breeze, OrderingService) {
    }
])

.factory('OrderingService', ['$http','mydatacontext', function ( $http, mydatacontext) {

    function loadDetails(filter) {
        console.log(breeze);

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/FabuServices/Status',
            params: { fromDate: filter.fromDate)
        }).then(function (result)
        { return result.data; })
    };  

}]);
```

Here is my second page which doesn't seem to recognize the factory from my first page.

```
'use strict'

angular.module('myApp')

.controller('QtyUsedDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', 'OrderingService', '$stateParams',
function QtyUsedDetailsCtrl($scope, OrderingService, $stateParams) {

    $scope.details = [];
    $scope.test1 = orderingService.test;


    $scope.init = function () {

        $scope.test = OrderingService.test;

        OrderingService.loadDetails($stateParams.fromDate)
       // orderingService.loadDetails('','','')
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.details = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.init();



}]);
```

ok. so I believe I have narrowed it down to the problem is just the service/factory.  when i call that, it breaks everything.

--------------edit!
ok, yes a service was helpful, but the actual problem is very silly.  I forgot to add the function to my return of the service!!!!   Now Can someone post an answer instead of a comment to the remaining problem?  $stateParams on the next page is NOT undefined.   in the console it says Object (but not expandable object and no details belong to the object).  And the variables that are "properties" of $stateParams are undefined.   you can see the code in my original post (above this edit).

Comment: You're missing `controller: 'QtyUsedDetailsCtrl',` in the first `state` object

Comment: why would that have to go in the first state.  that url doesn't use that controller at all.

Comment: the only thing i do notice is that I didn't provide any "path" for the QtyUsedDetailsCtrl.  Is that needed?  How would I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: also, i have the path in my index.cshtml file which is linked to the original module and controller

Comment: I think you'll start by changing `url: '/OrderingDetails',` to `url: '/OrderingDetails/{fromDate:string}',` and remove the `resolve` part, just fetch the parameter directly from the controller using `$stateParams`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105392/discussion-between-lisa-solomon-and-alon-eitan).

Comment: What do you mean by breaks everything? Is there an error in your console?

Comment: if I include a reference to the service, error says no such function OrderingService.loadDetails.  In addition, when I include it, it also breaks my angular variables on the html  it changes {{test}} to literal string.

Comment: IE finally gave me a better error!!!!  Object doesn't support property or method 'loadDetails'

Comment: Try changing the `factory` to `service` (i.e - `.service('OrderingService',...`)  and inside it, change `function loadDetails(filter) {` to `this.loadDetails = function(filter) {....` (read this relevant [tutorial](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html))

Comment: @AlonEitan - your comment like this is probably my answer, but how do I do it with multiple parameters?   
I think you'll start by changing url: '/OrderingDetails', to url: '/OrderingDetails/{fromDate:string}', and remove the resolve part, just fetch the parameter directly from the controller using $stateParams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is that you have to include it in the url: in order for $stateparams to know about it.
--I know there may be another option to use params: after the url and pass it in like that, but I couldn't get mine working.  The advantage of that is that the url is nice!
--Another issue I had which  I had to create a formatdate function to bypass, is that the angular or js didn't like when i sent in date objects, so i had to parse them as you can see....

Here is my updated code:

```
 .state('orderingDetails', {
        // url: '/orderingDetails:fromDate/:toDate',
        url: '/purchasingDetails/{fromDate}/{toDate}',
        templateUrl: '/App/js/ordering/partials/OrderingDetails.html',
        controller: 'QtyUsedDetailsCtrl',
        resolve: {
            details: function (OrderingService, $stateParams) {        
                return OrderingService.loadDetails($stateParams.fromDate,$stateParams.toDate);
```

and here is my $state.go call:

```
 $scope.openDetail = function (index) {
        var url = $state.href('orderingingDetails', { fromDate: $scope.formatDate($scope.filter.fromDate) , toDate: $scope.formatDate($scope.filter.toDate)} );            
        window.open(url, '_blank');    
    };
```